# DROOLS: Rules Events

Tags: drools

My question is:

In a Drools rule, there is a way to intercept the "success" event?
For better explain...  there's a way to call a listener when all the condition of a rule are true?

Note:
I dont want to set a global object (on session) to manage this condition on the "then" clause of a rule.

I'm searching for a solution already implemented on Drools

Rule sample

```
when
    $p : Person(name == "James")  
then
      // implicit callback to the listener managed by drools
```

Answer (score 0):

In package `org.kie.api.event.rule` there are `BeforeMatchFiredEvent` and `AfterMatchFiredEvent`. Implement interface `AgendaEventListener` with methods `void  afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event)` and/or `void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent event)`.

You can learn about the rule that was fired and the participating facts by evaluating the data passed with the event parameter.